# cakephp 1.3, how to use Paginator->sort() for two columns?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i have a simple application where i view some posts from a database and i use `Paginator->sort` to sort.

What i did is i duplicate everything so that i show the posts twice as well as the sorting.
something like this:

```
link_sort
post1
post2
post3
link_sort
post1
post2
post3
```

But when i click `link_sort` both post display get sorted, and i could see that because they are the same. But how can i make it unique so that one link sorts one post display and another one the other one  :).

here is some code:

```
<div class="sort"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('title');?></div>
<div class="sort"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('body');?></div>
<div class="content_title"><?php echo $post['Post']['title']; ?></div>
<div class="content_body"><?php echo $post['Post']['body']; ?></div>

<div class="sort"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('title');?></div>
<div class="sort"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('body');?></div>
<div class="content_title"><?php echo $post['Post']['title']; ?></div>
<div class="content_body"><?php echo $post['Post']['body']; ?></div>
```

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work -
create two different variables in the controller:

`$paginate1 = $this->paginate('conditions...')`
`$paginate2 = $this->paginate('conditions...')`

if am not mistaken I had a similar problem once and this is how I solved it.